# Screen getting frozen up/ stuck when navigating to different screen or component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I have this screen where I take data (as image URL ) from an API and display it as a gallery. The app works normally, but as soon I select an image from this gallery. Some screen/ components get frozen/ stuck.

The app doesn't get crash or log any error, it's just the screen gets frozen.

I think this issue is with the react-navigation.

Check the below video for reference.

[image]

if anyone else came across something like this just let me know